# Resharper inspection issue "Redundant dictionary 'ContainsKey' before adding to the collection"

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, resharper, code-inspection

Resharper is throwing this inspection issue:

> Redundant dictionary 'ContainsKey' before adding to the collection

At this part of the code:

```
var userPref = new Preferences { Key = key, Value = value };

if (this.preferencesDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    this.preferencesDictionary[key] = userPref;
}
else
{
    this.preferencesDictionary.Add(key, userPref);
}

return this;
```

I don't really think this is redundant. It is an error that I should skip? Or is there really an improvement here?

Comment: Why do you think it is not redundant?

Comment: @Sweeper because I have to check if it exists or not before overwriting the value to avoid an exception, isn't it?

Comment: No. It does not throw an exception when you are setting it, as the documentation I quoted says.

Comment: @Sweeper, well, you don't quoted anything here, I just asked to your question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the getter for the indexer of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` throws a `KeyNotFoundException` when the key is not found, the setter inserts the value into the dictionary if the key is not found.

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEAMACLARgBYBuAWACgsAmQqqgESgGMEoB7GCZATwB4iOOAUI4AfHgAeeALx4YAUwDuACgCUFSlIDaAIgBmHDnoC6cvHuA89WogE5VAEj0A5DnkVSWigA7suAGcAQjwAb11DYzMAXz1NIA==)

See [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-item(-0)).

> **Property Value**
>
> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is
> not found, a get operation throws a `KeyNotFoundException`, and a set
> operation creates a new element with the specified key.

`preferencesDictionary[key]` *looks like* you are calling the getter here, but since it is followed by the assignment operator `=`, you are actually calling the setter.

Comment: great! so `preferencesDictionary[key] = userPref;` will work as if the key doesn't exists, it will create it with that value

Comment: @SysDragon Yes, that's right.